# Android app is displaying an old image that was replaced

Tags: android, android-drawable

I am adding some icons from the drawables folder to a layout. I had an image that I replaced which got the same name as the old one. I have overridden the file, rebuilt the project and the Android Studio's graphical layout showed the new icon. However, when I ran the app, the old icon appeared. I went over all the drawables folders to see if there might be one with the old icon, but it was replaced in every folder. I also tried reinstalling the app and it's still showing the wrong icon.

Why won't the app show the correct icon?

Comment: probably cached. Try reinstalling the app

Comment: tried that and its still showing the wrong icon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What eventually happened is that the images were replaced in a library module, while the app module also contained the old image. Since the app resources overrides the library's resources, the old image was shown.

Answer (score 0):

May be due to some bug of Android Studio, Try it out it will work :

Delete `.apk` from local path manually (Path :  `\YourProjectFolder\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk`)

then **Rebuild Project** and finally **Run** it.

Comment: did not help. The code is in a library module so I eventually just deleted the entire build folder of both the library and the app, but it still did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Because of [instant run](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html) feature,

> Once your app is installed, Instant Run allows you to push code changes without building a new APK

new apk is not creating. Try after deleting apk file from path `...\apk\app-debug.apk`

Then build and generate apk again.

Comment: did not help. The code is in a library module so I eventually just deleted the entire build folder of both the library and the app, but it still did not help.

Answer (score 0):

**Rebuild** Your Project then it works fine

Comment: did not help. The code is in a library module so I eventually just deleted the entire build folder of both the library and the app, but it still did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Delete your icon from the drawables folder, set another image in the application instead of the deleted one, run the application, close the application, add your image again in the drawables folder, add it on your control and run again. It should work now.